# VBA IE automation - finding the last row of dynamic table

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am working on some code that would take information from Excel and transfer the information to a table on a website in IE. All has been well until now.

I'm currently stuck at a point and I can't seem to find any information to help.

What happens is there is a dynamic table per employee on the website. After clicking an "Add" button, a blank row is created, which is the one I want to transfer the information to. The problem is the row that is created ends up being the last row in the table. So when adding the row, it could be number 1, number 35, or whatever.

Is there a way I can set a reference to the last row of a dynamic IE table without having to know the number so the code would work for any employee?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about converting the elements in a column into an array.  Is that what you want?  If so, try one of these two scripts.

```
Sub MakeArray()
   Dim arr As Variant

   With ActiveSheet
      arr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range(.[A1], .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))
   End With
End Sub


Sub MakeString()
   Dim s As String

   Const DELIMITER = ","

   With ActiveSheet
      s = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range(.[A1], .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))), DELIMITER)
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response ryguy7272.  I need to be able to reference the last row of a table on a website so I can paste data from Excel to it.

Comment: I have tried the following - LastChild is my attempt to grab the last row of the table, but I'm not sure it is working.

Comment: With IE1
     While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
     Set lastrow = IE1.document.frames("mainParent").document.frames("main1").document.frames("SN").document.forms("AgentAppointments").document.getElementById("G_GD1").document.LastChild.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(0)
     lastrow.fireEvent ("onmouseover")
     lastrow.fireEvent ("onmousedown")
     lastrow.fireEvent ("onmouseup") 
     End With